# How to add customer details within a ArrayList?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm trying to create a customer. I'm trying to add each user input inside an arrayList and make it output towards the end. But, my output gives me some memory location.Can someone throw some light into this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter First Name: ");
    String firstName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Last Name: ");
    String lastName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Home Address: ");
    String homeAddress = input.nextLine();

    Customer cus = new Customer(firstName, lastName, homeAddress);

    System.out.println("\nWelcome: ");
    System.out.print(cus.getFirstName() + cus.getLastName());
    System.out.println("\n Your Shipping Address: ");
    System.out.print(cus.getHomeShippingAddress());

    List<Customer> customer = new ArrayList<Customer>();

    customer.add(cus);

    // Output the list contents
    printList(customer);

}

public static void printList(List<Customer> list) {

    System.out.println("Customers: ");

    for (Customer customer : list) {
        System.out.printf("%s", customer);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: You should override the `toString()` method for meaningful output.

Comment: I love the surreal calm before the storm of `toString` answers.

Comment: Comments solved this Question.;) String override.

Comment: Comments solve most questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to print an object, so it goes to its `toString()` method. You probably want to implement your own `toString()` method by overriding the one inherited from [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).

Something like:

```
@Override 
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    //build your string here. 
    //Perhaps by appending the customer's first and last name?
    return result.toString();
}
```

What you're currently seeing, inherited from [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), is this:

> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

Answer (score 4):

Override `toString` method of `Customer` object.

The current one is the default implementation.

Just in case you were wondering what @5c694a18 means : It is the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hashcode for your `Customer` object.

Answer (score 1):

As you din't **override toString** in Customer class, **Objects's toString** is invoked, which would return `NameOfTheClass +"@" +SomeHexNumber.`

```
 return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
```

Override `toString() method` in `Customer class` such that it prints the appropriate data .
something like below:

```
public String toString() {
return this.firstName+" " + this.lastName ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Customer` is an object, you need to override the toString() method to output the values you want about that object.